# SQL cursor over categories?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I tried to post full SQL code to walk you through the data and conversions, but it wouldn't post here.  Long story short, I end up with a data table like this:

```
Location  Date                     Direction  PreviousDirection  Offset
site1     2013-07-22 11:30:45.000   302        302                0
site1     2013-07-22 11:31:45.000   322        302               20
site1     2013-07-22 11:32:45.000     9        322               47
site1     2013-07-22 11:33:45.000     9          9                0
site1     2013-07-22 11:34:45.000     0          9               -9
site2     2013-07-22 11:30:45.000   326        326                0
site2     2013-07-22 11:31:45.000     2        326               36
site2     2013-07-22 11:32:45.000     2          2                0
site2     2013-07-22 11:33:45.000     2          2                0
site2     2013-07-22 11:34:45.000     2          2                0
```

Location,Date is the primary key.  I need help generating an [AdjustedDirection] column calculated as follows:

For first row (for each Location e.g. site1, site2): Since there is no previous row to calculate on, AdjustedDirection = first row's Direction.

After that, Second row AdjustedDirection: It's the first row's AdjustedDirection plus second row's offset.
Third row AdjustedDirection: It's the second row's AdjustedDirection plus third row's offset.
and so on...

I think this requires a cursor, but I don't know the syntax to do a cursor over multiple categories (Locations) and/or maybe there is a different answer.  I can't describe how many steps and how complicated the process was to get to this step. I'm so close to the end and totally stuck here!

If anyone has a clue how to populate these AdjustedDirection values, please prove your awesomeness.  Thanks!!

Results should look like this (date truncated for spacing, previous adjusted direction shown for clarity of how current row Adjusted is calculated):

```
Location  Date        Direction  Offset   PrevAdjDirection  AdjustedDirection
site1     11:30:45.000   302          0         302              302
site1     11:31:45.000   322         20         302              322
site1     11:32:45.000     9         47         322              369
site1     11:33:45.000     9          0         369              369
site1     11:34:45.000     0         -9         369              360
site2     11:30:45.000   326          0         326              326
site2     11:31:45.000     2         36         326              362
site2     11:32:45.000     2          2         362              362
site2     11:33:45.000     2          2         362              362
site2     11:34:45.000     2          2         362              362
```

thanks!

Comment: Please use a tag to identify the version of SQL Server. Also instead of describing the desired results with a word problem, SHOW US the adjusted data you want as a result of the query.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using correlated subqueries, some of which can be replaced by window functions (the version of SQL Server makes a difference here).

You want to change your logic.  Equivalent logic is:

1. For the first row, use the Direction
2. For subsequent rows, use the cumulative sum of the offsets excluding the first offset plus the direction from the first row.

The following calculates the appropriate variables using correlated subqueries, and then combines them using simple logic:

```
select t.*,
       FirstOffset + coalesce(SumEarlierOffsets - FirstOffset + Offset, 0) as AdjustedOffset
from (select t.*,
             (select Direction
              from t t2
              where t2.location = t.location
              order by date asc
             ) as FirstDirection,
             (select SUM(offset)
              from t t2
              where t2.location = t.location and
                    t2.date < t.date
             ) as SumEarlierOffsets,
             (select Offset
              from t t2
              where t2.location = t.location
              order by date asc
             ) as FirstOffset
      from t
     ) t
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up dumping the current data into a temp table and doing a WHILE UPDATE like this

```
SELECT Location, Date, Direction, Offset, Adjusted = NULL
INTO #results
FROM t1

WHILE (
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #results WHERE Adjusted IS NULL
) > 0
UPDATE TOP (1) t1
 SET Adjusted = ISNULL(t2.Adjusted,ISNULL(t2.Direction,t1.Direction)) + t1.Offset
 FROM #results t1 
 LEFT JOIN #results t2 ON t2.Location = t1.Location AND t2.Date =     DateAdd(minute,-1,t1.Date)
WHERE t1.Adjusted IS NULL
```

Thanks for the input and inspiration!